# Digitizing complex archaeological scenarios in various levels?

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, z-value, agisoft-photoscan

I don't know if this issue has already been answered, but I can't get my head around it. I used to do this in Illustrator, and there it was simply a matter of clicking "bring forward/bring back" etc.

We are about to start digitizing a lot of orthophotos of archaeological scenes generated in Agisoft Photoscan Pro. The excavations contains A LOT of wood and other artefacts. Various orthophotos covers several vertical layers (as we have dug down, each layers has been documented).

I have been digitizing two overlapping orthophotos, but the main problem is, that many of the artefacts or pieces of wood, overlap each other. 
I would really like to avoid, having to create layers for EACH artefact, and thus being able to contain fx all "Mandibles" in its corresponding Shapefile/layer. So, that the mandibles with the most positive Z-values, wouldnt be overlapped by wood with lower Z-values, simply because the layer for wood is above mandibles in the layers list.

Would it make a difference, if each polygon was assigned a Z-value (possibly extracted from a DEM)?

[image]

Comment: Yes. QGIS doesn't really do 3D currently. However storing the data with a z value gives you something to work with. It could be a layer designator (ie a depth/depth range of the image), or an actual elevation value. Getting that out of a DEM will be tough with what you want to do - it would likely have to be assigned manually from excavation notes. More of what you're talking about initially is 'draw order'. In GIS, it's usually last drawn is on top. If you can use 'symbol level drawing' (ArcGIS term) you can specify the z value such that things will draw in that order - but only in one layer.

Comment: Cheers Chris, thanks a lot. Guess I just have to create a ton of layers to cope with this, and wait for a possible update of QGIS able to handle 2.5D.